# How to get numbers from given GCD and LCM

Tags: java, math

I am trying to solve following problem.Finding numbers (two) form Given GCD and LCM(not necessarily correct). If given GCD and LCM are correct I need find out corresponding two numbers of them. Otherwise, GCD and LCM are not correct and off course no corresponding numbers exists.

[image: problem details]

Here is how I am trying to approach. And it's not the correct solution. How should i approach this properly.
[Note: Feel free to comment in any programming language or let me know the algorithm ]

```
public class GCD_LCM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b;
        a = scan.nextInt();
        b = scan.nextInt();

        int number = num(a,b);
        if(number==-1){
            System.out.println(number);
        }else {
            int fn =number;
            int sn =(a*b)/fn;
            System.out.println(fn+" "+sn);

        }
    }

    private static int num (int gcd, int lcm){
        int a =0;
        if(lcm>=gcd*2){
            for(int i =2; i<lcm/2; i++){
                if(lcm%i ==0){
                     a = lcm/i;
                }
            }
            return a;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific in what your issue is and what you need help with.

Comment: Can you click on problem details? https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9jL7.png

Comment: @SheikhHanif by more specific he meant what's the problem you are facing in your algorithm? some test cases where it fails? why do you think your algo is wrong?

Comment: If given gcd and lcm is correct I need to print in output any pair of number of this given gcd and lcm. If not correct then just print -1;

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm:

```
p = G*L
count = 0
for a = 1 to L
    if p%a == 0 and gcd(a, p/a) = G
        count++
    end if
end for
return count

    public class GCD
    {
        // Java function to calculate GCD
        // of two numbers
        static int gcd(int a, int b)
        {
            if (a == 0)
                return b;
            return gcd(b%a , a);
        }

        // Java function to count number 
        // of pairs with given GCD and LCM
        static int countPairs(int G, int L)
        {
            // To store count
            int count = 0;

            // To store product a*b = G*L
            int p = G*L;

            // p/a will be b if a divides p
            for (int a = 1; a<=L; a++)
                if ((p%a == 0) && gcd(a, p/a) == G)
                    count++;

           return count;
        }

        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            int G = 2, L = 12;
            System.out.print("Total possible pair with GCD " + G);
            System.out.print(" & LCM " + L);
            System.out.print(" = " + countPairs(G, L));

        }

    }
```

Comment: Is this really what the OP asked for?

Comment: How to get the pair of number and what if the given gcd and lcm is not correct. I got stuck to solve this two problem.

Comment: If gcd and lcm are not correct then it will output 0. -Sheikh Hanif

Comment: Need time optimization.

Comment: Ok- Sheikh Hanif, well my name is Adya and if it helped then you can upvote as well :)

Comment: The questioner does not have enough reputation to upvote your answer, though he explicitly says that your answer helped him. I upvoted your answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is often no unique answer to the problem. For example, if GCD=1 and LCM=6, possible answers include A=2, B=3 and A=1, B=6. If you need only one possible answer, just use A=GCD and B=LCM, with an error code if GCD does not divide LCM.

Here is code in Python 3. I'll leave converting the input to the integers to you.

```
def gcd_lcm(gcd, lcm):
    """Print two possible numbers given their GCD (Greatest 
    Common Divisor) and LCM (Least Common Multiple).
    If that is not possible, print -1."""
    if lcm % gcd == 0:
        print(gcd, lcm)
    else
        print(-1)
```

Comment: yes, seems like the gcd and lcm are almost always answers. sometimes there are many answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GCD_LCM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a, b;
        a = scan.nextInt();
        b = scan.nextInt();

        int number = num(a, b);
        if (number == -1) {
            System.out.println(number);
        } else {
            int fn = number;
            int sn = (a * b) / fn;
            System.out.println(fn + " " + sn);
        }
    }

    static int gcd(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a == 0)
            return b;
        return gcd(b%a , a);
    }

    private static int num(int gcd, int lcm) {
            int p = gcd * lcm;
            for (int a = 2; a <=lcm; a++) {
                if ((p%a == 0) && gcd(a, p/a) == gcd)
                    return a;
                }
                return -1;
        }

}
```

So far, this solution correct. Only problem is now "time limit exceed". How to optimize it.
Thanks @Ayda for your idea. It help me to improve my solution

Comment: both numbers must be a multiple of the gcd, so you can start a at gcd and increment a by the gcd